# WinError 123 The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect --> while importing transformers

Tags: python, anaconda, huggingface-transformers

I tried below code:

```
import transformers
```

and got below error:

```
import transformers

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .integrations import (  # isort:skip

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\transformers\integrations.py", line 58, in <module>
    from .file_utils import is_torch_tpu_available

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\transformers\file_utils.py", line 156, in <module>
    import sklearn.metrics  # noqa: F401

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .ranking import auc

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\ranking.py", line 35, in <module>
    from ..preprocessing import label_binarize

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._function_transformer import FunctionTransformer

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_function_transformer.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ..utils.testing import assert_allclose_dense_sparse

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\testing.py", line 718, in <module>
    import pytest

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytest.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import register_assert_rewrite

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import rewrite

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py", line 26, in <module>
    from _pytest.assertion import util

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\util.py", line 8, in <module>
    import _pytest._code

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .code import Code  # noqa

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\code.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pluggy

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .manager import PluginManager, PluginValidationError

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 11, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 547, in <module>
    __version__ = version(__name__)

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 509, in version
    return distribution(distribution_name).version

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 482, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 183, in from_name
    dist = next(dists, None)

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 425, in <genexpr>
    for path in map(cls._switch_path, paths)

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 449, in _search_path
    if not root.is_dir():

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1358, in is_dir
    return S_ISDIR(self.stat().st_mode)

  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1168, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\user1\\Spark\\python\\lib\\py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip:C:\\Users\\user1\\Spark\\python'
```

So, here is the error:
***OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\Users\user1\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip:C:\Users\user1\Spark\python'***

This is happening only for transformers package and rest like pandas or numpy or torch give no issues.
I see quite a few links giving solutions to this error, but more appear related to syntax of the code (like using double quotes or having an additional backlash).
What am I missing? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure of the reason for the error, but I could overcome the same by creating an environment and then installing transformers in it.
Hope this will help someone stuck with same error